# this.setState not updating the state unless I pass the whole object to it

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I have a component where I have a state with some properties. The constructor looks like this:

```
constructor (props, context) {
  super(props, context)

  this.state = {
    property1: '',
    property2: '',
    property3: '',
  }
}
```

Say I want to update `property1`, what I would usually do, is something like this:

```
this.setState({property1: 'my new property1'})
```

This however, is not working, the value of `property1` will not change. For me to update any of the states, I have to do the following:

```
let obj = this.state
obj.property1 = 'my new property1'
this.setState(obj)
```

I know for a fact that the previous way used to work without a problem. Has something changed? Are there certain circumstances which I can't simply set each state property?

Comment: Can you please define "not working"?

Comment: `property1` doesn't update. It continues as an empty string.

Comment: Can you please show where in your code you are calling `setState`? The entire function and how that function is called

Comment: As @MatthewHerbst mentioned, the full code would need to be looked at. Your problem with `setState` is very atypical.

Comment: This is this.setState({property1: 'my new property1'}) a truly valid one. There is no way that it don’t work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

setState works asynchronously.  If you call setState and then immediately check the value, it will not have updated yet.

```
this.setState({property1: 'my new property1'});
console.log(this.state.property1); //old value
```

if you want to wait for the new value, you can use the callback parameter in setState

```
this.setState({property1: 'my new property1'}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.property1);
});
```

The reason why you see the state updating when you use the whole object is because you are mutating the state by editing it, which is bad.

Comment: turns out I was having some issues due to having many `this.setState()` being called at once, so it seems that when I thought it was working, it was because I was mutating the whole object and NOT `this.setState`. I will have to rethink the code for this component, but at least I know what was going on.